# Array help in Powershell - correct syntax?

Tags: c#, arrays, powershell

I am writing a small test script to correctly verify some data.  I have the data passing via serial port to my program and all the data is in hex string's.  My code looks like a mess,  but it works.

I have this code working (as bad as it looks!),  it does eventually present the correctly formatted information,  but I have a feeling there is a much more efficient way to parse the data.

Below is a cluster line I call it  - it is putting my raw string into array, then only using the bytes that pertain to the data,  (the other bytes are responses to check sum/header and control sequence), so I strip those out,  then convert from hex to decimal to ascii. Probably a more efficient way to do all this?

```
$vin = $b[6,10,11,12,13,17,18,19,20,24,25,26,27,31,32,33,34] |
    ForEach-Object { [Convert]::ToInt32($_,16) } |
    ForEach-Object { [Convert]::ToChar($_) } |
    ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_ -NoNewLine }
```

Here is the raw data I get from device (example message):

> 49 02 01 00 00 00 4B 49 02 02 4C 31 54 44 49 02 03 35 32 36 33 49 02
>   04 35 42 34 37 49 02 05 35 38 38 36

(stream is 5 7byte messages, first 3 bytes are the header bytes)

The code above converts it to human readable field: KL1TD52635B475886

I use similar arrays to parse the response messages from my device,  just want to make sure I am not creating a mess!  Thank you!

I can provide more of my code,  but my question is on array/parsing use.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that looks wrong to me is that you seem to want to store the resulting string in a variable (`$vin`) but `Write-Host` will only output it on the screen.

You could turn also turn it into a function if you plan to use this repeatedly:

```
function ConvertFrom-DeviceHexData {
    param(  
        [Parameter(
            Position=0, 
            Mandatory=$true, 
            ValueFromPipeline=$true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)
        ]
        [String]$inputString
    )

    $inputArray = $inputString.Split(" ")

    $outputArray = $inputArray[6,10,11,12,13,17,18,19,20,24,25,26,27,31,32,33,34] |
        ForEach-Object { [Convert]::ToInt32($_,16) } |
        ForEach-Object { [Convert]::ToChar($_) } |
        ForEach-Object { $_ }

    $outputString = $outputArray -join ""

    $outputString
}
```

`"49 02 01 00 00 00 4B 49 02 02 4C 31 54 44 49 02 03 35 32 36 33 49 02 04 35 42 34 37 49 02 05 35 38 38 36" | ConvertFrom-DeviceHexData` returns `KL1TD52635B475886`.

Cannot say much about the seemingly "massive" syntax and the string manipulation, but your code looks quite clean to me.

Comment: Oh - a function!  That's awesome!

So like:> ConvertFrom-DeviceHexData (gc G:\hexdata.txt)   works like magic.   
Need to try the function with a Serial port read to really clean this up.  Thank you so much.  Not as bad as I thought it would be.

Comment: You're very welcome ^^. The usage here is to accept the answer you prefer (when there are multiple) by clicking the check mark next to the answer vote count (you can wait for more answers I'm clearly not the best here : ) ).

Comment: Can I feed the array the serial data as it reads it?  I was holding everything in variables, then converting, then output. 

Like?: $port.ReadExisting() | ConvertFrom-DeviceHexData

Comment: Edited my answer, this is now an advanced function (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847806.aspx).